# Asterisk -- VOIP prepaid account setup (outbound through remote asterisk server)

Tags: asterisk

I have a continental calling card and I'm not sure how to make it possible to dial out with my asterisk server.

It is a VOIP prepaid card.  I can call out on a softphone using their server address and my username and password.

I can't figure out my sip.conf or my dial plan.

Here is what I have.

sip.conf:

```
[continentalcard]
host=continental.com
defaultuser=username  ;; user on continental's server
secret=password
register => username:password@continental.com
context=global

[frank]
type=friend
defaultuser=frank ;; user on my local asterisk server
secret=password
host=dynamic
context=internal
```

extensions.conf:

```
[global]
CARD=SIP/continentalcard

[internal]
exten => 100,1,Dial(SIP/frank)
same => n,Hangup()
include => continentalcard

[continentalcard] ;; outgoing
exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,1,Dial(${CARD}/${EXTEN})
```

I get the following message on the CLI as I try to dial out 1-222-333-4444 (not the real number):

== Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
    -- Executing [12223334444@internal:1] Dial("SIP/frank-00000151",     "SIP/continentalcard:12223334444") in new stack
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[Oct  3 04:02:57] ERROR[22923]: netsock2.c:269 ast_sockaddr_resolve: getaddrinfo("continentalcard", "12223334444", ...): Servname not supported for ai_socktype
[Oct  3 04:02:57] WARNING[22923]: chan_sip.c:5866 create_addr: No such host: continentalcard:12223334444
[Oct  3 04:02:57] WARNING[22923]: app_dial.c:2345 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber absent)
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/frank-00000151' status is 'CHANUNAVAIL'

Comment: You have incorrect section in sip.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Filled sip.conf with the global context. Also just noticed your missing a / in extensions.conf. Please look below

You have your sip.conf formatted incorrectly.

```
[global]
register => username:password@continental.com
context=continentalcard

[continentalcard]
host=continental.com
defaultuser=username
secret=password
context=continentalcard
```

Registration should be placed under the [global] context in sip.conf.

Context should be continentalcard not global. When the softphone dials 1NXXNXXXXXX it should start using the continentalcard context from extensions and perform the Dial(${CARD}/${EXTEN})

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried changing my sip.conf by eliminating [continentalcard] and putting the other lines into [global], but still can't dial out. Does my extension look correct? `exten => _1NXXNXXXXXX,1,Dial(${CARD}/${EXTEN})` Also, I am a little confused as to how I should be responding.  Am I supposed to use the comments like I am doing?

Comment: Wait a minute... ignore that.  I just realized there is no global in sip.conf.  What I did was put it into [general] because I didn't understand what you were saying. I got it now. I changed to "context=global".  Now I am getting "Peer 'continentalcard' is now Reachable" in  the CLI and "sip show peers" lists continental, but I think my extension needs work now.

Comment: Good that it is registering. The context in sip.conf should be the context that SIP user has access to so this should be context=continentalcard or internal(internal just includes continentalcard on your post)

Comment: Actually, can you provide your softphone's sip.conf info? That is missing. Also provide a new CLI message of your attempt

Comment: I am using an ATA (SIP/frank). The sip.conf for that phone is added above. I can receive calls from other SIP phones on frank.  I also noticed that "sip show peers" shows a port 5090 for continental.

Comment: As far as using a softphone, I can use a softphone successfully by just plugging in the hostname, username, password, but this bypasses my Asterisk server (going directly to the continental host) and means I have to sit at the computer to dial out.  My purpose here is to use my ATA connected phone through my Asterisk server.

Comment: I think I see the problem, but don't know how, or even if, it is possible to do what I want.  The softphone works because I bypass my asterisk server and log on directly to continental. My phone on my local asterisk server is an analog phone hooked to an ATA as user frank on my local system.  So, I need to find a way to dial out as the continental user, but I still need to keep my internal ability to receive calls on my asterisk server under user frank--so both incoming and outgoing calls use the ATA phone regisered under user frank.